# Formatting a Streamfield image block

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I want to specify the HTML for each streamfield block with a for loop in my template. However, the image part is getting complaints, and I'm sure I'm not doing it the right way.

> Invalid block tag on line 15: 'image', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% load wagtailuserbar %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{page.title}}</h1>
    <small>{{page.date}}</small>

    {% for block in page.body %}
        {% if block.block_type == 'heading' %}
            <h2>{{ block.value }}</h2>
        {% elif block.block_type == 'quote' %}
            <blockquote class="blockquote text-center"><p class="mb-0">{{ block.value }}</p></blockquote>
        {% elif block.block_type == 'image' %}
            {% image block.value width-1200 class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{% wagtailuserbar %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include:

```
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}
```

My bad :)